# How can I parse this semicolon deliminted file?

Tags: matlab, file-io

I have a semicolon separated file in the following format:

```
Press;Temp.;CondF;Cond20;O2%;O2ppm;pH;NO3;Chl(a);PhycoEr;PhycoCy;PAR;DATE;TIME;excel.date;date.time
0.96;20.011;432.1;431.9;125.1;11.34;8.999;134;9.2;2.53;1.85;16.302;08.06.2011;12:01:52;40702;40702.0.5
1;20.011;433;432.8;125;11.34;9;133.7;8.19;3.32;2.02;17.06;08.06.2011;12:01:54;40702;40702.0.5
1.1;20.012;432.7;432.4;125.1;11.34;9;133.8;8.35;2.13;2.2;19.007;08.06.2011;12:01:55;40702;40702.0.5
1.2;20.012;432.8;432.5;125.2;11.35;9.001;133.8;8.45;2.95;1.95;21.054;08.06.2011;12:01:56;40702;40702.0.5
1.3;20.012;432.7;432.4;125.4;11.37;9.002;133.7;8.62;3.17;1.87;22.934;08.06.2011;12:01:57;40702;40702.0.5
1.4;20.007;432.1;431.9;125.2;11.35;9.003;133.7;9.48;4.17;1.6;24.828;08.06.2011;12:01:58;40702;40702.0.5
```

How can I parse this into a matrix in matlab? I don't care about the first row, but I would like the rest of the rows in the matrix. They don't need to be converted into doubles, the matrix can be comprised of strings. There are new lines in the file, which represent the end of a row. There are no semicolons before the new lines.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3):

Consider this code to read the data:

```
fid = fopen('file.txt','rt');
frmt = [repmat('%f ',1,12) '%s %s %f %s'];
C = textscan(fid, frmt, 'Delimiter',';', 'CollectOutput',true, 'HeaderLines',1);
fclose(fid);
```

First we read into the variable `C` the different components: the first twelve columns as numbers, next two as strings (we will convert them to serial date numbers in the next step), another numeric column, and finally a string one:

```
>> C
C = 
    [6x12 double]    {6x2 cell}    [6x1 double]    {6x1 cell}
```

As I mentioned, we can parse and covert `C{2}` into a serial date:

```
dt = datenum(strcat(C{2}(:,1),{' '},C{2}(:,2)), 'dd.mm.yyyy HH:MM:ss');
```

Now we can merge all of them into a cell array as a table. We use a cell array instead of a numeric matrix because the last column is still strings.

```
>> data = [num2cell([C{1} dt C{3}]) C{4}]

data = 
  Columns 1 through 7
    [0.96]    [20.011]    [432.1]    [431.9]    [125.1]    [11.34]    [8.999]
    [   1]    [20.011]    [  433]    [432.8]    [  125]    [11.34]    [    9]
    [ 1.1]    [20.012]    [432.7]    [432.4]    [125.1]    [11.34]    [    9]
    [ 1.2]    [20.012]    [432.8]    [432.5]    [125.2]    [11.35]    [9.001]
    [ 1.3]    [20.012]    [432.7]    [432.4]    [125.4]    [11.37]    [9.002]
    [ 1.4]    [20.007]    [432.1]    [431.9]    [125.2]    [11.35]    [9.003]
  Columns 8 through 14
    [  134]    [ 9.2]    [2.53]    [1.85]    [16.302]    [7.3466e+05]    [40702]
    [133.7]    [8.19]    [3.32]    [2.02]    [ 17.06]    [7.3466e+05]    [40702]
    [133.8]    [8.35]    [2.13]    [ 2.2]    [19.007]    [7.3466e+05]    [40702]
    [133.8]    [8.45]    [2.95]    [1.95]    [21.054]    [7.3466e+05]    [40702]
    [133.7]    [8.62]    [3.17]    [1.87]    [22.934]    [7.3466e+05]    [40702]
    [133.7]    [9.48]    [4.17]    [ 1.6]    [24.828]    [7.3466e+05]    [40702]
  Column 15
    '40702.0.5'
    '40702.0.5'
    '40702.0.5'
    '40702.0.5'
    '40702.0.5'
    '40702.0.5'
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use textscan for this.

```
 fid = fopen('data.txt'); %open file
 headers = fgetl(fid);    %get first line
 headers = textscan(headers,'%s','delimiter',';'); %read first line
 format = repmat('%s',1,size(headers{1,1},1)); %count columns and make format string
 data = textscan(fid,format,'delimiter',';'); %read rest of the file
 data = [data{:}];
```

Answer (score 1):

Evening Max.

I'm going to assume that you are already able to import the data from a file or otherwise get it into Matlab.  The method that I normally use for data like this leaves it in a column matrix of cells.  Each cell then contains a line of data from the file.

You can then convert the cell to a matrix of characters and use [regexp](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/regexp.html) to parse that data into an easier to use matrix with the top row being your header data.

If you get stuck just post up some code and we can work through it.

Cheers!

Update:

Here's the code I was talking about.

```
A = importdata('filepath\sample.txt') %This uses the newline on each line to make a new row.
B= [];
for(n = 1:size(A,1))
    B = [B;regexp(cell2mat(A(n)),';','split')]; %This uses the ; to split the string
end
```

Matlab indexing is always done in a (row, column) format.  So something like matrix(2,3) will call an item at the position of row 2, column 3.  Matlab also always indexs from 1, not 0 like in many other languages out there.

If you have a single row or a single column (commonly referred to as a vector) then you simply call matrix(4) and that returns the 4th element.  You can also have 3 or more layers to a matrix if you so desire.  Think a matrix of matrices if you want.

Cells are extremely useful when it comes to storing variable length data in a single location.  When data is stored in a cell it is still called in the same manner as you would a matrix but you have to convert it from the cell type to a matrix (cell2mat) for some uses.  You'll learn those pretty quick.  There's other ways to convert from cell as well, such as cell2num.

Hope that helps some more!

Comment: Just a note, it might not be the best practice to do it this way but off the top of my head it should get you started on the path.

Comment: I am actually looking for some matlab code. I would be able to solve this problem in many other languages, but I find writing matlab code to be very difficult. The research I'm doing now is my first experience with matlab. What is the syntax for a column matrix of cells (what is a cell?), and how can I actually use regexp. The documentation for matlab, in my opinion is overly verbose and never articulates the correct way to solve common problems. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Updated with a short example and some additional information for you.